# Convert formula into VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I use a formula in my sheet named as "TP" and I want to convert it into a VBA.

Any guidance will he helpful.

```
E11 = =PERCENTILE.INC($A$3:$D$30,50%)
E12 = =PERCENTILE.INC($A$3:$D$30,90%)
F11 = =PERCENTILE.INC($A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30:$C$3:$C$30:$E$3:$E$30,50%)
F12 = =PERCENTILE.INC($A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30:$C$3:$C$30:$E$3:$E$30,90%)
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840843.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way:

```
Range("E11").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC($A$3:$D$30,50%)"
```

to target other sheets:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC($A$3:$D$30,50%)"
```

To set `Sheet1.E11` formula to use a range which is itself on another sheet (`Sheet2[A3:D30]`):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(Sheet2!$A$3:$D$30,50%)"
```

Other way:
VBA:

```
WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range("$A$3:$D$30"), .50)
```

to target other sheets:

```
WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Sheets("Sheet1").Range( "$A$3:$D$30"), .50)
```

Comment: I get a peculiar error in my destination cell when I use the formula ni the above format : `Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE105").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(TP!$A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30:$C$3:$C$30:$E$3:$E$30,50%)` . ...The error in destination cell is #VALUE!

Comment: select that cell, click on yellow warning box and choose: [Show Calculation Steps] to see what happens. Are you sure you typed the formula correctly? what happen if you put that formula directly on the excel sheet (not by vba)?

Comment: also, when i copy-paste your formula to excel vba, a ?? mark appears at its end! `..$E??$30,50%)` check it (re-type that $E$3:$E$30 part in your vba code)

Comment: I get the same error #VALUE when I copy paste the formula to excel...and i'm not seeing any "??" in the

Comment: so its about your formula not the vba, try to find whats wrong with it e.g. by Show Calculation Steps i mentioned above.

Comment: I check the calculation step, the same formula was there but this - `TP!$A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30` was underlined

Comment: `TP!$A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30` is not a valid range address

Comment: in [Show Calculation Steps] window, press [Evaluate] button to step forward calcuating your formula. then see what happens. may be your data has some bad or empty values. are you sure the column 'D' shall be ommited from the formula `$C$3:$C$30:$E$3:$E‌​$30`?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Range("TP!E11").formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(OtherSheet!$A$3:$D$30,50%)"
```

etc.

Comment: What if the destination cell (E11) is in a different sheet?

Comment: @walterwhile Added reference for TP sheet and also for 'OtherSheet' which is the source one.